# Mongo db api get array from body

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, api

I am new in react js with mongdb so please let me know , how to get roles array from body.

```
body
{ fullname: 'tytyt',
  email: 'ytytyyuyuyu',
  password: 'tyty',
  contactno: 'tyty',
  address: 'tytyt',
  avatar: '',
  isActive: 'false',
  'roles[]': [ '5a5def3cca354d01e4e9d9f5', '5a5def6dca354d01e4e9d9f6' ] 
}
```

I have tried body.roles[] but unable to get value.

Thanks

Comment: why the property name 'roles[]'; it should be 'roles'; as per this  you need to access roles[][0] :)

Comment: Replace `roles[]` with `roles`

Comment: roles[][0] not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the property is named `'roles[]'` you should be able to access it with `body['roles[]']`.